# Issues creating Spark table from EXTERNALLY partitioned data

Tags: apache-spark, databricks

CSV Data is stored daily on AWS S3, as follows:

```
/data/year=2020/month=5/day=5/<data-part-1.csv, data-part-2.csv,...data-part-K.csv>
```

The query I would like to work:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE {table_name} (data1 INT, data2 INT)
    PARTITIONED BY (year INT, month INT, day INT)
    ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
    STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION '{file_location}' 
    TBLPROPERTIES ('skip.header.line.count' = '1')
```

Outcome: table is empty:

- attempted better specifying the location ".../data/year=*/month=*/day=*", instead of ".../data/".
- also attempted suggestions to run this command, which did not work:
  spark.sql("msck repair table database_name.table_name").

---

This version below is able to load data, but I need the year/month/day columns, idea here is filter by those to make queries faster:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE {table_name} (data1 INT, data2 INT)
    ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
    STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION '{file_location}' 
    TBLPROPERTIES ('skip.header.line.count' = '1')
```

Outcome: loads table as expected, but queries are very slow.

---

This version also loads a table, however, YEAR,MONTH,DAY columns are null:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE {table_name} (data1 INT, data2 INT, year INT, month INT, day INT)
    ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
    STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION '{file_location}' 
    TBLPROPERTIES ('skip.header.line.count' = '1')
```

---

I am assuming the first query is the correct way to load this data, based on documentation. Looking at the resultant schema, that also seems to be correct - however I cannot get it to actually load any data.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried `ALTER TABLE {table_name} RECOVER PARTITIONS`? also i hope you are specifying file location till root directory of partitions

Answer (score 0):

Check if this helpful-

> Please note `sparkSession` is created without hive support

### 1. Create dummy test dataframe and store it as csv with `year`, `month` & `day` partition

```scala
 val df = spark.range(1).withColumn("date",
      explode(sequence(to_date(lit("2020-06-09")), to_date(lit("2020-06-20")), expr("interval 1 day")))
    ).withColumn("year", year($"date"))
      .withColumn("month", month($"date"))
      .withColumn("day", dayofmonth($"date"))
    df.show(false)
    df.printSchema()

    /**
      * +---+----------+----+-----+---+
      * |id |date      |year|month|day|
      * +---+----------+----+-----+---+
      * |0  |2020-06-09|2020|6    |9  |
      * |0  |2020-06-10|2020|6    |10 |
      * |0  |2020-06-11|2020|6    |11 |
      * |0  |2020-06-12|2020|6    |12 |
      * |0  |2020-06-13|2020|6    |13 |
      * |0  |2020-06-14|2020|6    |14 |
      * |0  |2020-06-15|2020|6    |15 |
      * |0  |2020-06-16|2020|6    |16 |
      * |0  |2020-06-17|2020|6    |17 |
      * |0  |2020-06-18|2020|6    |18 |
      * |0  |2020-06-19|2020|6    |19 |
      * |0  |2020-06-20|2020|6    |20 |
      * +---+----------+----+-----+---+
      *
      * root
      * |-- id: long (nullable = false)
      * |-- date: date (nullable = false)
      * |-- year: integer (nullable = false)
      * |-- month: integer (nullable = false)
      * |-- day: integer (nullable = false)
      */
    df.repartition(2).write.partitionBy("year", "month", "day")
      .option("header", true)
      .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
      .csv("/Users/sokale/models/hive_table")
```

### File structure

```
    /**
      * File structure - /Users/sokale/models/hive_table
      * ---------------
      * year=2020
      * year=2020/month=6
      * year=2020/month=6/day=10
      * |- part...csv files (same part files for all the below directories)
      * year=2020/month=6/day=11
      * year=2020/month=6/day=12
      * year=2020/month=6/day=13
      * year=2020/month=6/day=14
      * year=2020/month=6/day=15
      * year=2020/month=6/day=16
      * year=2020/month=6/day=17
      * year=2020/month=6/day=18
      * year=2020/month=6/day=19
      * year=2020/month=6/day=20
      * year=2020/month=6/day=9
      */
```

### Read the partitioned table

```scala
val csvDF = spark.read.option("header", true)
      .csv("/Users/sokale/models/hive_table")

    csvDF.show(false)
    csvDF.printSchema()

    /**
      * +---+----------+----+-----+---+
      * |id |date      |year|month|day|
      * +---+----------+----+-----+---+
      * |0  |2020-06-20|2020|6    |20 |
      * |0  |2020-06-19|2020|6    |19 |
      * |0  |2020-06-09|2020|6    |9  |
      * |0  |2020-06-12|2020|6    |12 |
      * |0  |2020-06-10|2020|6    |10 |
      * |0  |2020-06-15|2020|6    |15 |
      * |0  |2020-06-16|2020|6    |16 |
      * |0  |2020-06-17|2020|6    |17 |
      * |0  |2020-06-13|2020|6    |13 |
      * |0  |2020-06-18|2020|6    |18 |
      * |0  |2020-06-14|2020|6    |14 |
      * |0  |2020-06-11|2020|6    |11 |
      * +---+----------+----+-----+---+
      *
      * root
      * |-- id: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- date: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- year: integer (nullable = true)
      * |-- month: integer (nullable = true)
      * |-- day: integer (nullable = true)
      */
```